# Case statement taking in null

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SO I now have my query which reads HD0/HD1/HD2/HD3/HD4 but running into an issue, where if i have a null value i then get duplicate // ei. hd0///hd3/
any ideas

```
Hd0
||'/'||
Case
When table.hd1 <>00
then HD1_ABR 
end
||'/'||
case
When hd2 <>00
then HD2_name
end
||'/'||
case
When hd3 <>00
then HD3_name
end
||'/'||
case
When hd4 <>00
then HD4_name
end) as Name,
```

Comment: Taking apart your first `CASE` statement, you're saying "if `hd1` isn't zero, then `HD1_ABR` else NULL. The others are similar. Oracle is giving you exactly what you're asking for. What value do you want if `hd1` (or `hd2` or `hd3` or `hd4`) *is* zero?

Comment: if its zero i dont want any value but i also dont want th / that follows the HD

Comment: OK, in that case the answer from @DazzaL is what you want. The trick is to move the `/` inside the `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you can change your case to

```
rtrim(Hd0
||'/'||
Case
When table.hd1 <>00
then HD1_ABR ||'/'
end
||
case
When hd2 <>00
then HD2_name||'/'
end
||
case
When hd3 <>00
then HD3_name||'/'
end
||
case
When hd4 <>00
then HD4_name
end, '/') as Name,
```